# jquery Find div by ID from an ajax output

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, find

I'm afraid very similar question has been asked already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042499/how-to-find-the-div-html-from-the-ajax-post-result-in-jquery), but for some reason it simply outputs "null".

I'm trying to find a div html from an ajax output by id. Below is my script.

```
// LOAD NAVIGATION
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url:  'includes/content/bookingsystem/b_navigation.php',
  data: thisButtonType + '=true&loadNav=date',
  success: function(output) { 

    alert(output); // Outputs correctly two divs #navDay, and #navMonth

    alert($(output).find('#navDay').html()); // Results into "null"

    $('#navDay').html($(output).find('#navDay').html()); // Results in an empty div, since it overwrote the html with 'null' - nothing.

    //$('#navDay').replaceWith($('#navDay', output)); // Same here - nada.
    //$('#navMonth').html($(output).find('#navMonth').html());

  }

});
```

The first alert(output) results this:

```
<div id="navDay">Im day nav!</div>
<div id="navMonth">Im month nav!</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap your two divs in an outer div if you expect to be able to use `.find()` or `$(selector, context)` - those functions only find *descendent* nodes, and you have two sibling nodes in your HTML without a real parent.

You could either do that wrapping server side, or use `.wrap()`.

Furthermore, the `.html()` function only returns the *inner* content of your tags, not the tags themselves.

Assuming (based on your use of `.replaceWith`) that your intention is to replace entire elements, and not just text, I'd go for:

```
<div>
    <div id="navDay">Im day nav!</div>
    <div id="navMonth">Im month nav!</div>
</div>
```

At which point this line from your previously non-working code will work too:

```
$('#navDay').replaceWith($('#navDay', output));
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you a whole lot. Didn't realize that it had to be wrapped like that.

Comment: I could never find a way to properly execute a `.wrap()` on `output` as @Alnitak suggested. I tried to `.wrap()` so that I could do a `.find()`, but i didn't get anywhere. Wound up going and different route and just used `.filter()` as suggested at http://stackoverflow.com/a/400232/923817

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// LOAD NAVIGATION
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url:  'includes/content/bookingsystem/b_navigation.php',
  data: thisButtonType + '=true&loadNav=date',
  success: function(output) { 

    //alert(output); // Outputs correctly two divs #navDay, and #navMonth

    //alert($(output).find('#navDay').html()); // Results into "null"

    $('#navDay').html($('#navDay', $(output).wrap("<div />")).html()); // Results in an empty div, since it overwrote the html with 'null' - nothing.

    //$('#navDay').replaceWith($('#navDay', output)); // Same here - nada.
    //$('#navMonth').html($(output).find('#navMonth').html());

  }

});
```